# Firebase error message Fatal Exception: j.c

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I developed an app and track bugs and errors with firebase crashlytics. But, some error message written :

Fatal Exception: j.c

without a detailed explanation of the error. What's the meaning of this error? How do we track the error from the error message?

Edited :

This is my gradle configuration :
[Gradle config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGXq1.png)

And this is the crash report message on crashlytics
[Crashlytics error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8oRV.png)

This is code at onMessageReceived method in FcmMessagingService class :

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)

    if (remoteMessage.notification != null) {
        val title = remoteMessage.notification?.title
        val message = remoteMessage.notification?.body
        val clickAction: String? = remoteMessage.notification?.clickAction
        sendNotification(title ?: "", message ?: "", clickAction ?: "")
    }

    if (remoteMessage.data.values.isNotEmpty()) {
        var title = ""
        var body = ""
        var tag = ""
        var click_action = ""
        if (........) {
          .......
        } else {
            title = remoteMessage.data.get("title")!!
            body = remoteMessage.data.get("body")!!
            tag = remoteMessage.data.get("tag")!!
            click_action = remoteMessage.data.get("click_action")!!
            setIntentFromData(title ?: "", body ?: "", tag ?: "", click_action ?: "")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Having an image of the crash report would be nice, but for the look of it "j.c" it seems the code was obfuscated. This can happen if the mapping file wasn't uploaded. Are you using proguard? could you share the gradle config? Did you follow this doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android

Comment: @Gerardo I've post image of crash report and gradle config. Yes, I use progruard

Comment: Do you continue having this issue? In the gradle screenshot it is missing  the part related to the mapping file:  mappingFileUploadEnabled false
This parameter will create the gradle tasks in charge of upload the mapping file to Crashlytics so it can deobfuscate those crash reports.